# How to solve the parallelization of for loop error with joblib: "assignment destination is read-only"?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

```
>>> joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(joblib.delayed(im_ll)(i) for i in range(0,2045))
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "<stdin>", line 92, in im_ll
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    self.retrieve()
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result 
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 435, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\sdontula\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

I was trying to run the specific function `im_ll` for 2000+ times, it will take 40+ minutes using `for` loop, so I tried parallelizing the loop using `joblib`. The function runs smoothly when called individually but I face the above error when I run it using the `joblib.Parallel`. How can I resolve the issue?